# is there a way to set environment variables for windows using rust

Tags: windows, rust

well, I am new to rust, I am building a command-line application and I am using rust...

I know how to set system environment variables using a batch script, but I want to implement everything in rust, so is there a way to set environment variables for windows using rust.

I tried **set_var(KEY)** but it only works for the currently running process...

so please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check window api ?

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to use it.

Comment: Environment variables are normally scoped for the currently running process. Do you want to make it user-wide or system-wide?

Comment: i want make it user-wide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the registry to do this, so a necessary disclaimer: using the registry incorrectly can mess up your system.

On Windows, user environment variables are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\`. The Rust library [winreg](https://docs.rs/winreg/0.7.0/winreg/) makes this pretty straightforward:

```rust
use winreg::{enums::*, RegKey};

fn main() {
    let hkcu = RegKey::predef(HKEY_CURRENT_USER);
    let (env, _) = hkcu.create_subkey("Environment").unwrap(); // create_subkey opens with write permissions
    env.set_value("TestVar", &"TestValue").unwrap();
}
```